# Traffic control (TC) command with u32 filter - Not working (RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument)

Tags: linux, centos, tc

I am working on college assignment, in which our teacher asked us to block some BPDU packets (which are generated by interface, incoming packets are blocked by BPDU guard) using traffic control **tc**'s **u32** filter. With u32, we have **destination mac** at **-14 till -8**, I want to match mac with pre-defined mac using **tc**.

Now, Whenever I run any **tc** command (mentioned below) on my **CentOS 7** with **kernel 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64** it shows error when I run following command (copied from [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.qdisc.filters.html)):

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol 1 prio 10 u32  match ip tos 0x10 0xff  flowid 1:4
```

> **Error: RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument We have an error talking to the kernel**

Also tried commands posted in [this question](https://boerde.lists.lartc.narkive.com/GhiJEp5m/lartc-marking-packets-by-mac-addr-using-tc-filter-u32-match#post4), after running the following command:

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol 1 prio 1 u32 match u16 0x0800 0xFFFF at -2 match u16 0xM4M5 0xFFFF at -4 match u32 0xM0M1M2M3 0xFFFFFFFF at -8 flowid 1:20
```

following error occured:

> **Illegal "match"**

I tried commands which are [given here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.qdisc.filters.html) and [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.adv-filter.u32.html). I even tried **tc's man commands**, but same error occur.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you should include exact commands you are using in your question. "error talking to kernel" might suggest relevant modules missing not loaded. it's also possible your toolset is outdated (although tc / qos doesn't change much).

Comment: Updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: I'm surprised you describe something related to ethernet, MAC and bridges, while your failing command is IP over PPP (ie: not ethernet ,no MAC and no bridge). Your commands were copied but changed (eth0 into ppp0). the linked chapter 9.6 depends on previous chapters like 9.5 (where a qdisc is added first) . In short, you should read the whole documentation

Comment: Ok thanks @A.B I will do that, but these commands are supposed to run fine? My question is that why aren't these commands running ? what am I missing here?

Comment: So did you read the missing part in chapter 9.5 yet?